# css add padding to background position [ css only ]

Tags: html, css

I have this div:

### Original:

[image: 1]

### Wanted output:

I want to line go to the end of div like this:

[image: 2]

*Note: div have fluid with ! If I resize screen, output will be same*

### Edit:

### No HTML markup edit ( CSS only )

### My try:

but if I set `background-repeat` to `x-repeat` the image in background will go under date too, and I want to avoid that:

[image: 3]

### Example:

http://jsbin.com/OCuxOKi/2/edit

http://jsfiddle.net/xVW4u/

### HTML:

```
<div class="date">
25.4.2013
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.date {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('time_line.png');
  background-position: 80px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: does this can be a solution? [http://jsfiddle.net/JonnyMe/xVW4u/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/JonnyMe/xVW4u/1/)

Comment: @Jonathan I was considering that, but I can't edit HTML.

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak If you don't care about much browser support then you can try this. http://jsfiddle.net/crazyrohila/xVW4u/8/

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak I edited my answer, check if it's what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't edit your HTML markup, there is a way with CSS3 pseudo-class `:after`
Add the background image as `:after`.

I created quickly a [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/otenC). Just play with the `:after` and you will achieve a solution where you won't need to edit your HTML markup.

**HTML**

```
<div class="date">
   25.4.2013
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.date {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.date:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:'';

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;

  background-image: url('http://mike.php5.sk/public/time_line.png');
  background-position: 80px center;
}
```

Learn how to use CSS3 pseudo-classes on [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/)

As Ruddy said in the comment, using CSS3 will limit the browser support. [Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) is an overview which browser can use CSS3 pseudo-classes.

Comment: Hmm, this will limit browser support. Just pointing this out to them.

Comment: @Ruddy: Thanks. Added caniuse.com reference

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a way to cheat it, I don't think it would be the best way but it does work.

HTML:

```
<div class="date"> <span>25.4.2013</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.date {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('http://mike.php5.sk/public/time_line.png');
    background-position: 80px center;
    background-repeat: x-repeat;
}
.date span {
    background: red;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/xVW4u/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="date">
    <div style="background: red; display: inline-block; padding: 0px 10px;">
        25.4.2013
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.date {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('http://mike.php5.sk/public/time_line.png');
}
```

**EDIT:**

I figured how to do. It does exist a property called `background-size`:

HTML:

```
<div class="date">
    25.4.2013
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.date {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('http://mike.php5.sk/public/time_line.png');
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-position: 80px center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JonnyMe/xVW4u/11/

Comment: Your CSS-only solution is good. But why is the stripe thicker than without the `background-size`? And why do the 100% 100% work? but +1

Comment: @user2413035 I think it is browser-related, in FF I can see it correct, in Chrome seems thiker. With `100% 100%` you say it need to be same height and width of the div. The first is the `width` and the second the `height`. Try to play a little to adjust thikness.

Comment: @user2413035 Try with `background-size:100% 19px;`

Comment: @user2413035 as to why it works it is because first the css says the image must be the same width of your div and then it says it must be shifted by 80px.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by adding an extra div.

```
<div class="date">
    <span>25.4.2013</span>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Then de CSS:

```
.date {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
}
.date span{
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.date div{
  background-image: url('time_line.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  margin: 0 0 0 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```